# How to define a tuple of randint without repeating code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I often get to use tuples of randint for color-values and such like

```
(a, b, c) = randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)
```

when I thought there has to be a better way - is there?

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: You can start with `randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)`.

Comment: You can use a generator expression, but for *just 3 variables* that's just as verbose and thus no improvement.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable way to get exactly three random integers in a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

**Using numpy?**

1

```
import numpy as np
tuple(np.random.randint(256, size=3))
# (222, 49, 14)
```

---

Multiple

```
import numpy as np
n=3
[tuple(i) for i in np.random.randint(256, size=(n,3))] # list
# (tuple(i) for i in np.random.randint(256, size=(n,3))) # generator
# [(4, 70, 3), (10, 231, 41), (141, 198, 105)]
```

---

**Speed** comparison

```
(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.31 µs per loop

```
tuple(random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3))
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.96 µs per loop

```
tuple(np.random.randint(256, size=3))
```

> **100000 loops, best of 3: 4.58 µs per loop**

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b, c = [randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Why create a whole new list first? Just replace the `[...]` with `(...)`.

Comment: Also, this is only adding cognitive load, it's not really an improvement.

Comment: If you are going todo this, you might as well use a generator expression...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's an improvement in that it makes it clear that all 3 variables are initialized with the same expression, and it guards against the errors common in copy-paste code. Personally, I find any additional cognitive load minimal, but I don't know how others would judge it.