# generate list of no repeated tuples and doesn't have both of (a,b) and (b,a) tuples, python

Tags: python, numpy, random

How can I generate a list of tuples whose elements are not repeated? In addition, if there is (a,b) tuple in list, (b,a) would not be generated in this list.

I use code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515276/how-to-define-a-tuple-of-randint-without-repeating-code/#answer-45515488), but it doesn't provide second condition:

```
[tuple(i) for i in np.random.randint(5242, size=(500,2))]
```

Comment: How long is the list? So any random tuple of numbers?

Comment: List has 500 tuples, each number is in range of 0 to 5242 @Dani Mesejo

Comment: In fact, list contains 500 tuples whose elements are in range of 0 to 5242@Dani Mesejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're going to get any kind of one-liner to do that cleanly. I'd just do something like:

```
num_set = set()
while len(num_set) < 500:
    a, b = random.randint(0, 5242), random.randint(0, 5242)
    if (b, a) not in num_set:
        num_set.add((a, b))
num_list = list(num_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're interested in something more like a set of sets rather than purely tuples. If your objects are sortable, you can use this common hack:

```
included_set = set()
included_list = list()
input_list = np.random.randint(5242, size=(500,2))

for (a, b) in input_list:
    sorted_version = tuple(sorted((a, b)))
    if sorted_version not in included_set:
        included_set.add((a, b))
        included_list.append((a, b))
```

If your objects are not sortable, but are hashable and comparable, you could tweak the above to work anyway:

```
for (a, b) in input_list:
    if (a, b) not in included_set and (b, a) not in included_set:
        included_set.add((a, b))
        included_list.append((a, b))
```

Note that you only need to keep separate `included_list` and `included_set` if you want to retain the ordering of the input list. If not, and if you don't care about the tuple ordering `(a, b)`, just use:

```
uniques = {tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in input_list}
```

Answer (score -2):

you could just use `random.sample` from the python built-in library:

```
nums = random.sample(range(5242), 1000)
res = [tuple(v) for v in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2])]
```

Comment: Because random.sample returns unique elements, this code means that if (a, b) is present, (a, c) can never be chosen. So it's introducing a bias into the returned values (which may or may not matter to the OP).

Comment: good point. i considered that but since OP says "whose elements are not repeated" i thought it fit the bill.

Comment: For more than 500, I get this error : in sample raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative

Comment: since nowhere in this comment does `500` exist, i'm going to assume you changed 1000 to something > 5242.

Comment: I didn't expect you to predict using this code for more than 500. I just wanted to tell others your code gets error for very large amount such as 14000. And it doesn't mean this code is wrong!!@acushner